# Irregular internet connection in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: internet, connection

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 desktop edition in my new computer . I have a problem with the internet connection (Ehternet). Actually, my internet works for 20 sec and it stops for 40 to 60 sec. This cycle repeats and makes me difficult to work. Please help me. I am sure someone solved this problem. I tried editing the /etc/reolv.conf from

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

to:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

But the problem is not solved.

Here is the `ifconfig` output: (I use eth0)

```
eth0:   Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr f0:79:59:39:ae:80   
        inet addr:115.145.183.44 Bcast:115.145.183.255 Mask:255.255.255.0  
        inet6 addr: fe80::f279:59ff:fe39:ae80/64 Scope:Link 
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1  
        RX packets:195975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
        TX packets:15856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
        RX bytes:32299713 (32.2 MB) TX   bytes:2260481 (2.2 MB)  
        Memory:fb300000-fb37ffff    

eth1:   Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr f0:79:59:39:ae:7f    
        UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 
        RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000   
        RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)     
        Interrupt:20  
        Memory:fb700000-fb720000  

lo:     Link encap:Local Loopback    
        inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0   
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host      
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1 
        RX packets:3647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
        TX packets:3647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0      
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0   
        RX bytes:350955 (350.9 KB) TX bytes:350955 (350.9 KB)
```

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface 
    product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-LM 
    vendor: Intel Corporation 
    physical id: 19 
    bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0 
    logical name: eth1 
    version: 05 
    serial: f0:79:59:39:ae:7f 
    capacity: 1Gbit/s 
    width: 32 bits 
    clock: 33MHz 
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair  
    resources: irq:97 memory:fb700000-fb71ffff memory:fb739000-fb739fff ioport:f020(size=32)  

*-network 
    description: Ethernet interface 
    product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection 
    vendor: Intel Corporation 
    physical id: 0 
    bus info: pci@0000:0f:00.0 
    logical name: eth0 
    version: 03 
    serial: f0:79:59:39:ae:80 
    size: 100Mbit/s 
    capacity: 1Gbit/s 
    width: 32 bits clock: 33MHz 
    capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.2.13-k duplex=full firmware=3.25, 0x800005cf ip=115.145.183.44 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s  
    resources: irq:16 memory:fb300000-fb37ffff ioport:c000(size=32) memory:fb380000-fb383fff
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a desktop version of Ubuntu, I believe setting nameservers to 127.0.0.1 is fine as long as you have the correct info in network-manager. Not very logical, but it works like that for me.
You might want to check if the ethernet interface you are using is actually working. I've lost quite a few before, but if you don't mind using command line a bit, you could try bonding the interfaces and running two network cables to your pc to ensure connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to check my ethernet interface is woking? My internet connection is working for 20 sec and goes off for a while and comes back. Does not it say my ethernet interface is OK? My dmegs log for eth1 records that  eth1 is  Link is up and then TSO disables then link is down then IPV6 (ADDRCONF) link is not ready.. then link is up and then disabling TSO and it repeats..Can you find out what is going on here?

Comment: You could try a different ethernet cable, switch, etc.
I'm guessing it's a public IP though, so I'm not sure of the specifics. It might be easier to connect it to a local network for testing purposes.